# Polymorphic (Generic) Functions as Arguments in C++

Tags: c++, generics, variadic-templates, higher-kinded-types, higher-rank-types

I am developing a relatively simple program (a calculator actually). However, I have decided to make all components of my program as generic as possible because:

1. It's good practice.
2. It keeps things interesting.

As part of this program I am using a `Tuple` class that I am writing. I know that a class already exists, but I like having complete control over my code and this is only an exercise.

One thing I need to do is transform a tuple of expressions (where expressions themselves are generic) into a tuple containing the result of the expressions' evaluations. In short, I have (with trivial parts left out):

```
template <class T>
class Expression {

    public:
        virtual T Eval() = 0;

    // ...
};

template <class First, class ... Rest>
class Tuple {

    // ...

    private:
        First first;
        Tuple<Rest ...> rest;
};
```

And I would like to specialize over a tuple of a generic type like this:

```
template <template <class> class R, class First, class ... Rest>
class Tuple<R<First>, R<Rest> ...> {

    // and here is the problem:
    Tuple<First, Rest ...> Transform(function<template<class T> T(R<T>)>);
};
```

After which I could do this:

```
template <class T> // There has to be a better way to do this
T Eval(Expression<T>& expr){
    return expr.Eval();
}

// ...
Tuple<First, Rest ...> tuple = exprs.Transform(Eval);
```

There are a few places here where I am not sure how to go about things and a real expert who could help me out here would be appreciated. I expect this code will not compile because of minor flaws but that isn't the point - My primary worry is the line I marked. If I recall correctly from the brief period I learned Haskell this function should be of Rank-2 (If not please comment and I will remove the tag). It just doesn't look right. Is there any way to do this?

**Update:**

I was advised to try pass a functor with a generic `operator ()` as a template argument but that didn't work either.

Comment: Try `boost::mpl::transform`.

Comment: @n.m. - That doesn't provide the functionality I am looking for.

Comment: @dyp - Yes, I do, That's a pure virtual function. But that's not the point. The point is - How do I pass a generic function as an argument?

Comment: @dyp - Yes, I'll edit that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this pretty simply without C++14 at all. I'm going to assume a few things about how your `Tuple` is constructed, namely that these two ctors exist:

```
Tuple(First, Rest... );                // (1)
Tuple(First, const Tuple<Rest...>& );  // (2)
```

We need one type trait: given a function that we're transforming with, we need to know what types it produces:

```
template <typename T, typename F>
using apply_t = decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<T>()));
```

(God I love C++11)

With that, we can determine the return type easily, and it's just a matter of calling the function recursively:

```
template <typename First, typename... Rest>
struct Tuple
{
    template <typename F>
    Tuple<apply_t<First, F>, apply_t<Rest, F>...>
    Transform(F func)
    {
        return {func(first), rest.Transform(func)}; // hence the need
                                                    // for ctor (2)
    };
};
```

(Depending on how you wrote your `Tuple` you may or may not need a base case for a trivial transform that just returns a `Tuple<>`, or a base case that just returns a `Tuple<apply_t<First, F>>`. Either way, not a big deal).

And you don't even need to specialize `Tuple` at all. You just need to pass in the right functors. For instance:

```
struct Zero
{
    template <typename T>
    int operator()(T ) { return 0; }
};

struct Incr
{
    template <typename T>
    T operator()(T x) { return x + 1; }
};

Tuple<int, double, char> tup(1, 2.0, 'c');
auto z = tup.Transform(Zero{}); // z is Tuple<int, int, int>{0, 0, 0}
auto i = tup.Transform(Incr{}); // i is Tuple<int, double, char>{2, 3.0, 'd'}
```

[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60c85b7d6c6b9114)'s a full code example, logging all the types too. Of course, with C++14, we can do those inline:

```
auto i2 = tup.Transfom([](auto x) -> decltype(x) {return x+1; });
// i2 is a Tuple<int, double, char>{2, 3.0, 'd'};
// without the trailing decltype, it gets deduced as Tuple<int, double, int>.
```

Answer (score 3):

The usual trick in C++14 is to use some `index_sequence` (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence)) and then something like:

```
template<typename ... Args, size_t ... I>
auto evaluate(Tuple<Args ...> const& t, index_sequence<I...>)
{
    return make_tuple(evaluate(get<I>(t))...);
}
```

See, e.g., [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17856416/2412846) for an example of this approach (the only difference is that here additionally a function call is invoked).

Thus, what you need here in your `Tuple` class for this is:

- An implementation of a custom `get` function which behaves similarly to `std::get`, i.e. accepts variadic index arguments.
- An implementation of a custom `make_tuple` function which behaves similarly to `std::make_tuple` and constructs a tuple from a comma-separated list.

Further, you require a function template `evaluate` which is able to evaluate a single expression, but I guess you have this already.

---

**EDIT:** I just realized that the above might not be very helpful for you. Rather it should be noted that you can do that also recursively:

```
template<typename ... Args>
auto evaluate(Tuple<Args ...> const& t)
{
    return tuple_cat(make_tuple(evaluate(t.first)), evaluate(t.rest));
}

template<typename T> auto evaluate(Tuple<T> const& t) { return evaluate(t.first); }
```

Again, you require a `make_tuple` function, a tuple concatenator `tuple_cat` and a single-expression evaluator `evaluate`.

Comment: An equivalent for std::get and std::make_tuple are easy and I have already implemented them in a somewhat different scenario elseware. I still don't see how to write the Transform function, which is the important part.

Comment: @user2008934: [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1383d7fbf9846ccb) is a basic implementation which should get you close to what you want to do (for an exact match you'd need `tuple_cat`, which I was too lazy to implement). Hope it helps.

Comment: How is this generic? I'm not seeing how to extend this in a similar case (say a tuple of lists of different types -> a tuple of the sum of each list) - It would seem you have to repeat this code for every such case.

Comment: @user2008934: you give a tuple to the evaluate function and get returned a tuple which contains the transformed types. In the example, I've passed a `Tuple<int,int>`, applied a function `double evaluate(int)`, and would have got back a `Tuple<double,double>` (if a `tuple_cat` were available -- actually it is a `Tuple<double, Tuple<double> >`). The generic thing here is: *that code works like this for any type and any evaluation function*.

Comment: But you have to write a new evaluate function every time. What if I wanted to turn a tuple of lists of different types and transform it into a tuple of their sums? You would have to write everything again but replace evaluate with sum! I want to be able to pass sum as an argument and be done with it.

Comment: @user2008934: No, just use a function template `template<typename ExpressionType> auto evaluate(ExpressionType)` which evaluates arbitrary expressions. You called this `Eval(Expression<T>)` in your OP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65541/discussion-between-user2008934-and-davidhigh).

Comment: I actually curry out the function and then partially apply it recursively.