# How to drop element from std::tuple?

Tags: c++, c++14, stdtuple

Given a

```
struct A{}; struct B{}; struct C{};
std::tuple<A,B,C> tabc;
```

How to drop second element `B` from it to get `tuple<A,C>`, like

```
std::tuple<A,C> tac = drop<B>(tabc);
```

or the same

```
std::tuple<A,C> tac = drop<1>(tabc);
```

I assume this produces a new type with copies of elements.

Comment: Use `std::get` to fetch each "survivor" from the original tuple into the new one. That's it; no tricks here, just the direct approach.

Comment: `auto tac = std::make_tuple(std::get<0>(tabc), std::get<2>(tabc));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fairly simple enough to code with meta-programming techniques:

```
template<size_t drop, size_t ...ixs>
constexpr auto calc_drop_sequence_dropper(std::index_sequence<ixs...>)
{
    return std::index_sequence<(ixs >= drop ? ixs + 1 : ixs)...>{};
}

//Creates a monotonically increasing sequence on the range [0, `count`), except
//that `drop` will not appear.
template<size_t count, size_t drop>
constexpr auto calc_drop_copy_sequence()
{
    static_assert(count > 0, "You cannot pass an empty sequence.");
    static_assert(drop < count, "The drop index must be less than the count.");
    constexpr auto count_sequence = std::make_index_sequence<count - 1>();
    return calc_drop_sequence_dropper<drop>(count_sequence);
}

template<typename Tuple, size_t ...ixs>
constexpr auto copy_move_tuple_by_sequence(Tuple &&tpl, std::index_sequence<ixs...>)
{
    using TplType = std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>;

    return std::tuple<std::tuple_element_t<ixs, TplType>...>(
        std::get<ixs>(std::forward<Tuple>(tpl))...);
}

template<size_t drop, typename Tuple>
constexpr auto drop_tuple_element(Tuple &&tpl)
{
    using TplType = std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>;

    constexpr size_t tpl_size = std::tuple_size<TplType>::value;

    constexpr auto copy_seq = calc_drop_copy_sequence<tpl_size, drop>();

    return copy_move_tuple_by_sequence(std::forward<Tuple>(tpl), copy_seq);
}
```

The principle function is `drop_tuple_element`, which does what your hypothetical `drop` function does. Of course, if you're dropping multiple elements, you want to drop them all at once, rather than individually. So you'll need to modify the code.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this answer how to make a subtuple:

[Creating a sub-tuple starting from a std::tuple<some_types...>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17854219/creating-a-sub-tuple-starting-from-a-stdtuplesome-types)

Read it. By making a subtuple routine you can make a generic version of `drop`:

```
 template<size_t index, typename Tuple>
 auto Drop(const Tuple& t)
 {
     return std::tuple_cat(
         subtuple_v2<0,index>(t), 
         subtuple_v2<index+1, std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>(t));
 }
```

Where `subtuple_v2<a,b>` is an extended version from the post that generates subtuple from indexes `a` to `b`.

Comment: I'd add `constexpr`

Answer (score 1):

[std::tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) is immutable, you can't drop or remove.

> std::tuple is a fixed-size collection of heterogeneous values

Depending on your C++ taste, create a new tuple with [std::get(std::tuple)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) and [std::make_tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple)

```
auto tac = std::make_tuple(std::get<0>(tabc), std::get<2>(tabc));
```

Or with C++14

```
auto tac = std::make_tuple(std::get<A>(tabc), std::get<C>(tabc));
```

Comment: Thank you. But i am looking for a more generic way. I know a type/index to drop and do not know others.

Answer (score 0):

If  you know indices of objects A and C in the tuple then you can use the function `std::get` with the template parameter `size_t`. Otherwise you can use the function `std::get` with type template parameter.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

struct A
{
};

struct B
{
};

struct C
{
};

int main() 
{
    auto t1 = std::make_tuple( A(), B(), C() );
    auto t2 = std::make_tuple( std::get<A>( t1 ), std::get<C>( t1 ) );
    auto t3 = std::make_tuple( std::get<0>( t1 ), std::get<2>( t1 ) );

    return 0;
}
```