# C++ subtuple from tuple given variadic index sequence

Tags: c++, tuples

Assume I have a `std::tuple`, I'd like to write a function which receives a tuple and a variadic sequence outputting a subtuple containing the columns corresponding to those indexes.

Example usecase:

```cpp
std::tuple<int, char, float, std::string> t{1, 'd', 3.14, "aaa"};

auto subtuple = extract_subtuple(t, 0, 2);
// returns std::tuple<int, float>(1, 3.14)
```

Is this possible ?

I had a look at this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17854219/creating-a-sub-tuple-starting-from-a-stdtuplesome-types) but in the end I didn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: but why you want to use indices like that? They must be compile-time constants anyway so there's no difference from `std::make_tuple(std::get<0>(t), std::get<2>(t))`

Comment: I'm trying to implement a parallel method that basically selects tuples according to indices, then I need to pass the indexes and I need a sort of variadic behavior that I'm failing to implement

Comment: Please provide some more context and a code example for the use case. It is not generally possible to create a sub-tuple based on a runtime index range since the type would dependent on the index sets (and using something like `std::variant` would be practically impossible for all possible index sets).

Comment: You could do `auto subtuple = extract_subtuple<0, 2>(t);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it directly because tuple indices should be constant expressions and function parameters are [never constant expressions](https://wg21.link/p1045) even if corresponding arguments are. You have two main options.

Firstly, you could make indices template parameters:

```
template<std::size_t... Is, class... Ts>
auto extract_subtuple(const std::tuple<Ts...>& tuple) {
    return std::make_tuple(std::get<Is>(tuple)...);
}

auto subtuple = extract_subtuple<0, 1>(t);
```

Secondly, if you want to make indices function parameters, you could wrap them into types:

```
template<class... Ts, class... Indices>
auto extract_subtuple(const std::tuple<Ts...>& tuple, Indices...) {
    return std::make_tuple(std::get<Indices::value>(tuple)...);
}

template<std::size_t I>
using Idx = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>;

auto subtuple = extract_subtuple(t, Idx<0>{}, Idx<1>{});
```

Comment: the first version works perfectly for what I need, thanks a lot. I'm accepting your answer